# BLUE from calculus

Tags: self-study, calculus, blue

Let $p'\beta$ be an estimable LPF. Suppose
that $l'y$ is the candidate which must satisfy the unbiasedness
condition and the minimum-variance condition. Formulate this as an optimization problem with Lagrange multipliers, and show that the optimum $l'y$ is $p'(X'X)^{-}X'y$

This is from Jammalamadaka & Sengupta. I'm quite stuck in this one as how should I form the equation for lagrange multipier, I'm sure I can do the rest afterwards. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Any linear function of $y$ can be written as $l'y$ for some $l$ by Riesz representation theorem. So you need to check $\mathbb{E}(l'y)=p'\beta$.
$$L(\beta,\lambda) = (y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta) + \lambda'(l'X\beta-p'\beta)$$
Take the derivative and set it to zero to get your result. Estimability arument might come into play somewhere.